# Apache Alias - Chiliproject

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup Chiliproject (a ruby application for project management)
I have setup my Apache already. However I want the Chiliproject to be like http://abc.com/Chiliproject as I want the abc.com to be used for other application.

Following is my Chiliproject vhost setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/chiliproject/public

  Alias /chiliproject /var/www/chiliproject/public

 <Directory /var/www/chiliproject/public>
   Options -MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to abc.com, the Chiliproject page will appear but when I go to abc.com/chiliproject, I will reach the 404 page not found instead.
If I change the DocumentRoot to /var/www, the page abc.com will be what I want, but the abc.com/chiliproject will comes to the 'Directory view' of my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to get the virtual host setup right.
First you need to ensure the passenger module of Apache is installed. (else just install it)
Below are my final virtual host that works

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
    ServerName abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    Alias /chiliproject /var/www/chiliproject/public

    <Location /chiliproject>
        PassengerBaseURI /chiliproject
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/chiliproject
    </Location>

    <Directory /var/www/chiliproject/public>
        RailsBaseURI /chiliproject
        Options -MultiViews
        Allow From All
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```